# Выводить значимость на тепловую матрицу корреляций

Tags: python

Возможно ли выводить на тепловые матрицы корреляций уровень значимости  (например, если pvalue<=0.05, то рядом с числом выводится одна звездочка "*", а если pvalue<=0.01, то две звездочки "**"). Ну или хотя бы чтоб просто выводились только значимые значения, у которых уровень значимости pvalue<=0.05, а остальные оставлять пустыми.
Никак не получается это сделать.

Строится стандартно.

```
corrmat = df.corr()

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 6))

#mask = np.triu(df.corr())
sns.heatmap(df.corr(), annot=True, vmin=-1, vmax=1, center=0, cmap ='RdYlGn' )
plt.title('Корреляции между шкалами')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.xticks(rotation=80)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример исходных данных: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kCQQbvMVMEP8lkd2fO7QjKiuRfJzWpDTB6lOm0BvAwE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Пример исходных данных?

Comment: А в каком формате удобнее всего их выкладывать? Пока залиты через гугл-таблицу, не знаю, насколько это удобно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя ранее сформированные данные с аннотациями из вашего предыдущего вопроса это можно сделать так:

```
sns.heatmap(df.corr(), annot=df_corr, fmt='s', vmin=-1, vmax=1, center=0, cmap ='RdYlGn')
```

Обратите внимание на эти два параметра: `annot=df_corr, fmt='s',`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @IoIo И всё же постарайтесь научиться гуглить. Либо на английской части Stackoverflow либо ещё где-то в интернетах есть все ответы, нужно только научиться их искать и применять :)  Хотя в русскую часть SO их тоже, конечно, надо постепенно приносить и мы с вами этому способствуем сейчас...

Comment: Пытаюсь... не всегда успешно. Когда-то информации не нахожу, когда-то запрос может формирую неправильно, иной раз могу не понять сами ответы. Но пытаюсь. Спасибо!